# How to manage two configuration global elements in Mulesoft xml

Tags: xml, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I am new to the Mulesoft and facing issue while managing two configuration global elements, one from main xml file and other from imported XML. Both are configured for error handling. Is there any way to handle this type of situation.
I am getting error, when having two configuration global elements.
" Configuration elements can be only once in the XML"

Comment: Please share an example of the XML.

Comment: Also please share the complete error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @aled   , I have tweaked the approach and used one configuration element

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer for others to benefit.